# Google spreadsheet ImportRange - need to improve my workaround

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am pretty new to this forum and also to the google scripts. I have never actually learned JavaScript or any other programming language, however I was forced to start using then since the time I chose the google apps as my main platform for my small business.

My problem is in google ImportRange function limitation to 50 on every spreadsheet. I created a model, where every customer has his own spreadsheet with his personal data, deadlines, etc. located in his own folder in google drive.

I also created a spreadsheet called "Organizer", Organizer has two functions -

1) create automatic correspondention using autoCrat script,
2) show deadlines for every costumer and sort them by priority.

So i need to be able to share / import / copy data from all customer spreadsheets to the "Organizer". Because there are 50+ costumer spreadsheets, I had to give up on ImportRange function and instead of that I am using a simple script to copy files from every spreadsheet directly:

```
function ImportDataRange() {

// rown number.1
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Databaze");
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1)
var id = range.getValue()
var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("Raw");
var range = sheetraw.getRange("A2:AB2");
var data = range.getValues();

sheet.getRange("B2:AC2").setValues(data)

// row number.2
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Databaze");
var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1)
var id = range.getValue()
var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("Raw");
var range = sheetraw.getRange("A2:AB2");
var data = range.getValues();

sheet.getRange("B3:AC3").setValues(data)
}
```

This script actually works well, but problem is, when I want to add new costumer spreadsheet to "Organizer" using this method, I have to manually add new copy of whole code for every new row and also change the output range of imported data and location of source file ID in "Organizer".

Does anybody know some kind of workaroud, which will help me to add new rows / costumer data easier / automatically ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use a loop of some sort. *I haven't tested the code below*, but based on your example, I think this should work for you.

```
function ImportOtherSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Databaze");

  // Get the first column
  // lastRow() - 1 because we're starting at row 2
  var sheetIds = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);

  // For each ID in the id column
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetIds.length; i++) {
    var id = sheetIds[i]; // Get the id from the Array

    // Get the new sheet, range and values
    var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("Raw");
    var range = sheetraw.getRange("A2:AB2");
    var data = range.getValues();

    // Get the local range, and write the values
  sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, data[0].length).setValues(data)
  }
}
```

As you learn more about GAS and JS, take advantage of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) and the [GAS Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunetelly, your code doesnt work for me. It runs without errors, but doesnt update my spreadsheet based on IDs in first column.

Strange is that I really dont know why this is not working. I already did some studies on "loop" in JS and for what I have learned your code seems to me right and logic. Because of this I cant figure out where should be the problem. Is there any other way how to get this function working?

Thank you!

Comment: In GAS you should use the `Logger.log("message")` to out put some information to make sure you're getting the right information. Is there any specific behavior that the notice with what I've provided? If you can describe what is happening maybe I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I took the fooby´s code and after long trial-and-error procedure I came with code that is working for me, so if anyone is interested, here it is:

```
function ShowDataFromOtherSheet() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Databaze");

var ids = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
var id = ids[i];

var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("Raw");
var range = sheetraw.getRange("A2:AB2");
var data = range.getValues();

sheet.getRange(i + 2, 2, 1, data[0].length).setValues(data)

    }
}
```

And thank you fooby - i would not make it without your help!